# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender while openning STS 3.9.2 in linux machine

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, m2e

While opening STS in linux machine, I am getting the following error.

org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
10:17:15,300 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
10:17:15,301 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
10:17:15,301 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
10:17:15,303 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Setting up default configuration.
10:17:15,508 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
10:17:15,521 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/home/ekowsal/project/tosca-d/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.8.2.20171007-0217.xml]] every 60 seconds.
10:17:15,521 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
10:17:15,536 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:17:15,537 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
10:17:15,766 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
10:17:15,769 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:73)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:48)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:35)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:54)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:275)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:147)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:129)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:185)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
        at      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender cannot be found by ch.qos.logback.classic_1.1.2.v20160208-0839
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
        at      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:60)
        at      ... 17 common frames omitted
10:17:15,770 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:81 - ActionException in Action for tag [appender] ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException:ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:82)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:275)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:147)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:129)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:185)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
        at      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:73)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:48)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:35)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:54)
        at      ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender cannot be found by ch.qos.logback.classic_1.1.2.v20160208-0839
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
        at      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:60)
        at      ... 17 common frames omitted
10:17:15,771 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.EclipseLogAppender]
10:17:15,772 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [EclipseLog]
10:17:15,777 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.MavenConsoleAppender]10:17:15,779 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [MavenConsoleLog]
10:17:15,779 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
10:17:15,779 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [FILE]. Did you define it below instead of above in theconfiguration file?
10:17:15,779 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.
10:17:15,780 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
10:17:15,780 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [EclipseLog] to Logger[ROOT]
10:17:15,780 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [MavenConsoleLog] to Logger[ROOT]
10:17:15,782 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.ning.http.client] to INFO
10:17:15,782 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
10:17:15,782 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@15f38869 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core.templates.TemplateProcessor).

Comment: I have this issue too with Eclipse for JavaEE 4.7.3